# Verify otp sent in android

Tags: android

I am trying to send otp to my phone and if i enter the correct otp only, the user should sign in. My problem is that even if I enter the wrong otp, it allows me to sign in, I cannot find out the wrong part. Can anyone help please. Here is my code. When I debug, it enters the catch block

Here is the code I used to verify my otp

```
private void verify() {
    String input_code =otp.getText().toString();
    try {
        if(!verification_code.equals("")) {
            verifyPhoneNumber(verification_code,input_code);
            otp.setError("Incorrect otp");
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

I am validating also, but no way

```
if(otp.getText().length()==0) {
    otp.setError("enter otp");
    return;
}

verify();
```

Here is `verifyPhoneNumber()`

```
private void verifyPhoneNumber(String verifyCode, String input_code) {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential=PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verifyCode,input_code);
    signInWithPhone(credential);
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of `verifyPhoneNumber()` method

Comment: post your verifyPhoneNumber function that function might be causing exception

Comment: @Lucifer..I have posted

Comment: try   verify(); method in else loop

Comment: @nishant I have posted the code

Comment: @jigarsavaliya Tried that also, same error

Comment: check exception using LOG. It will easy to solve your problem instead of guessing?

Comment: try this,
`String input_code =otp.getText().toString().trim();`
instead of 
`String input_code =otp.getText().toString();`

and 
`if(!verification_code.isEmpty())`
instead of 
`if(!verification_code.equals(""))`

Comment: @AnuragShrivastava its not working

Comment: It shows the error..incorrect otp and it doesnot return; instead it goes to next activity@AnuragShrivastava

Comment: did you try this [tutorial.](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-adding-sms-verification-like-whatsapp-part-2/)

Comment: Everything works fine, I am able to send and verify, and its says its an incorrect otp..but I need it to return in same page without proceeding to next activity, what happens is it moves to next activity even if it shows its wrong otp@AnuragShrivastava